# User role editor - Add download files capability

Tags: user-roles, plugin-recommendation, capabilities

I've got User Role Editor plugin installed and i want to add a capability for download files.

I've got some downloads in a custom post type called 'products'. I want only people who are logged in to be able to download or view these files. If a user isn't logged in they get redirected to a login/registration page, then they log in and get redirected back to the product page.

User role editor has a capability for upload files so was wondering if it can be used to download files as well.

Or should i use some other plugin or something to get this?

Comment: Can any logged in user download these files?  Or only certain users?

Comment: Any logged in user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're just checking to see if they are a logged in use, you can just use the `is_user_logged_in()` function to check if they are logged in and if so, display the download link, if not, don't display the download link.

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to display the download link even if the user isn't logged in? because if a user isn't logged in and it doesn't show the download links they will just get a blank section. I want the links to show for everybody but only users that are logged in can actually view or download the files.

Comment: In that case, you have a couple of options, either you can create a download script that will check if the user is logged in and if so, allow the download if not, block it. Or, you can just use another plugin.  I found this plugin here that I think would fit your needs.  Check it out and let me know. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/download-monitor/

Comment: I've looked at the plugin and i think it will be good for a different section of the site which will be a members only download section. However it's only good for downloads uploaded with that plugin. It won't work for my needs because the files i want this to work on are uploaded via a custom field on my custom post type.

Comment: I'm using download monitor to get pretty much what i needed.